# VB.net Background worker closes before loop ends

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a button which calls my background worker (BackgroundWorker1) now, this works fine and inside of my backgroundworker_DoWork handler, it has a while loop which compares 2 numbers the first number being 0 and the second 255. Now, I also have a progresschaged handler which should update my ListView when called but the background worker only runs the loop 3 times. The code for this can be found below:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
        While startIP(1) < endIP(1) ''ONLY RUNS 3 TIMES?
            test = test + 1
            worker.ReportProgress(0, "Check")
            startIP(1) = startIP(1) + 1
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        MetroListView1.Items.Add(startIP(0) & "." & startIP(1) & "." & startIP(2) & "." & startIP(3))
        MetroListView1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        MessageBox.Show("Closed.")
    End Sub
```

I have checked that the 2 variables have values and they do. StartIP reaches 3 before the loop stops and the RunWorkerCompleted handler is ran. I'm really confused why this is doing this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you have declared the two arrays startIp and endIp? I bet you have two string arrays here

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know how many had fallen on this thing called [Option Strict Off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement)
In your project this option is set to Off and this means that your compiler allows strings that contains only digits to be handled as they were numbers.
But that's not true when comparing two strings.

In a comparison between the string "3" and the string "255" the lesser one is "255" not "3" because the first char in "255" is alphabetically lesser than the first (and only) char in "3". Thus your loop ends when the first string reaches the value of 3.

Here an example to be run with Option Strict Off

```
Sub Main
    Dim i As String = "0"
    Dim e As String = "255"

    While i < e
        i = i + 1
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    End While
    ' Exits when i = "3"
End Sub
```

You should declare the two arrays (startIP and endIP) as two integer arrays and do mathematical operation on numbers not on strings. Also I really suggest you to avoid this problems setting Option Strict to On in the properties of your project

Comment: I have edited the while so that the values are now converted into integers, although, I am still having the same problem. `While Convert.ToInt32(startIP(1)) < Convert.ToInt32(endIP(1)) + 1
            test = test + 1
            worker.ReportProgress(0, "Check")
            'MessageBox.Show(startIP(0) & "." & startIP(1) & "." & startIP(2) & "." & startIP(3))
            startIP(1) = startIP(1)) + 1
        End While`

Comment: Not sure what else is at play here. If I apply the conversion to the example above the loop runs 255 times as expected. Are you able to use the debugger, place a breakpoint at the loop condition and inspects the variable values? Or you can simply add a Console.WriteLine with the values of startIP(1) and endIP(1) inside the loop. You will be able to see the output through the Output window of Visual Studio (Debug->Windows->Output)

Comment: I've tested the console.writeline now, It seems to be working there. So I must also have an issue with the listview updating as the listview starts at 60 then displays 119, 176, 233 and 256

Comment: @FUS234 If you still do "startIP(1) = startIP(1) + 1" then you should really declare startIP as an integer and not a string.